# Obter lista de itens de um listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou criando um windows form no C# com uma listbox e gostaria que as informações salva dentro dessa listbox fossem salvas em uma lista para poder usar em outra classe.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Muito simples, o próprio controle do listBoxjá contem a lista(listBox.Items)...
caso ainda queira transferir os mesmos para uma lista especifica bastar criar a lista e atribuir os itens do listBox a ela.

```
 var MinhaLista= listBox.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();
```

se o listbox for de valores monetários, inteiros ou qualquer outro tipo, basta modificar o cast para o tipo desejado, Exemplo(int):

```
var MinhaLista= listBox.Items.Cast<Int>().ToList();
```